# How do I do something like numpy's arange in Go?

Tags: python, numpy, go

Numpy's arange function returns a list of evenly spaced values within a given interval with float steps. Is there a short and simple way to create a slice like that in Go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None that I am aware of. You can define [your own](http://play.golang.org/p/MSASVhSsRi) though:

```
import "math"

func arange(start, stop, step float64) []float64 {
    N := int(math.Ceil((stop - start) / step));
    rnge := make([]float64, N, N)
    i := 0
    for x := start; x < stop; x += step {
        rnge[i] = x;
        i += 1
    }
    return rnge
}
```

which returns:

```
arange(0., 10., 0.5)
[0 0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 5 5.5 6 6.5 7 7.5 8 8.5 9 9.5]
```

Corresponding to the Python:

```
>>> np.arange(0., 10., 0.5)
array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  2.5,  3. ,  3.5,  4. ,  4.5,  5. ,
    5.5,  6. ,  6.5,  7. ,  7.5,  8. ,  8.5,  9. ,  9.5])
```

Note that because of the way I defined the iteration, you cannot use negative steps in my simple Go version, but you can define something a bit more robust if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

Based on **val**'s solution, I would suggest to avoid using "x+=step" because depending on the limits and the step, rounding errors will accumulate and you may leave the last value undefined or even worse, try to define the N+1 value, causing a panic.

This could be solved with:

```
func arange2(start, stop, step float64) []float64 {
    N := int(math.Ceil((stop - start) / step))
    rnge := make([]float64, N)
    for x := range rnge {
        rnge[x] = start + step*float64(x)
    }
    return rnge
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/U67abBaBbv

Comment: Late to the game, but you're correct. I see that if I use this input: `arange(0.2, 10 + 0.001, 0.001)` it will try to insert one too many values.